# WordPress database error: [Table './db/wp_usermeta' is marked as crashed

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I can't login wp-admin.

*Info : I disabled all plugins. ( not working )*

debug;

```
WordPress database error: [Table './karabuyu_db/wp_usermeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired]
SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id IN (1) ORDER BY umeta_id ASC
```

I checked wp_usermeta table and got this error.

[image: wp-usermeta error]

I dont have backup , how can i fix this ? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repair the table in PHPMyAdmin. What output does it generate?

Comment: hello , now is index no working. admin ok but , Fatal error: Call to undefined function bp_core_get_user_domain() in /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/parts/header/top-menu.php on line 45 not working

Comment: ok now is working. ( i disabled and active buddypress) working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux server for your WordPress, such as CentOS, you can try the MySQL command to check the MySQL database status and try to repair the database.

WordPress Envinronment:

```
CentOS 6.6
WordPress 4.5.28
PHP 5.6.24
MySQL 5.5.50
```

Just use the following MySQL command to check the status of MySQL database.

```
//the following wordpress is the database name of wordpress
mysqlcheck -u root -p wordpress
//and then just input the password of the database
```

example:

```
# mysqlcheck -u root -p wordpress
Enter password: 
wordpress.wp_bwg_album                             OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_album_gallery                     OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_file_paths                        OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_gallery                           OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_image                             OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_image_comment                     OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_image_rate                        OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_image_tag                         OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_shortcode                         OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_theme                             OK
wordpress.wp_commentmeta
warning  : 9 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
status   : OK
wordpress.wp_comments
warning  : 7 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
status   : OK
wordpress.wp_cptch_images                          OK
wordpress.wp_cptch_packages                        OK
wordpress.wp_cptch_whitelist                       OK
wordpress.wp_links                                 OK
wordpress.wp_ngg_album                             OK
wordpress.wp_ngg_gallery                           OK
wordpress.wp_ngg_pictures                          OK
wordpress.wp_options
warning  : Table is marked as crashed
warning  : 53 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
error    : Record at pos: 488396 is not remove-marked
error    : record delete-link-chain corrupted
error    : Corrupt
wordpress.wp_postmeta
warning  : 53 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
status   : OK
wordpress.wp_posts
warning  : 32 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
status   : OK
wordpress.wp_sbi_instagram_feed_locator            OK
wordpress.wp_sbi_instagram_feeds_posts             OK
wordpress.wp_sbi_instagram_posts                   OK
wordpress.wp_smush_dir_images                      OK
wordpress.wp_term_relationships
warning  : 12 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
status   : OK
wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy
warning  : 9 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
status   : OK
wordpress.wp_termmeta                              OK
wordpress.wp_terms
warning  : 2 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
status   : OK
wordpress.wp_usermeta
warning  : 16 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
status   : OK
wordpress.wp_users
warning  : 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
status   : OK
```

And then use the following MySQL command to repair the database.

```
//the following wordpress is the database name of wordpress
mysqlcheck -u root -p wordpress --auto-repair
//and then just input the password of the database
```

example:

```
# mysqlcheck -u root -p wordpress --auto-repair
Enter password: 
wordpress.wp_bwg_album                             OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_album_gallery                     OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_file_paths                        OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_gallery                           OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_image                             OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_image_comment                     OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_image_rate                        OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_image_tag                         OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_shortcode                         OK
wordpress.wp_bwg_theme                             OK
wordpress.wp_commentmeta                           OK
wordpress.wp_comments                              OK
wordpress.wp_cptch_images                          OK
wordpress.wp_cptch_packages                        OK
wordpress.wp_cptch_whitelist                       OK
wordpress.wp_links                                 OK
wordpress.wp_ngg_album                             OK
wordpress.wp_ngg_gallery                           OK
wordpress.wp_ngg_pictures                          OK
wordpress.wp_options
warning  : Table is marked as crashed
warning  : 53 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
error    : Record at pos: 488396 is not remove-marked
error    : record delete-link-chain corrupted
error    : Corrupt
wordpress.wp_postmeta                              OK
wordpress.wp_posts                                 OK
wordpress.wp_sbi_instagram_feed_locator            OK
wordpress.wp_sbi_instagram_feeds_posts             OK
wordpress.wp_sbi_instagram_posts                   OK
wordpress.wp_smush_dir_images                      OK
wordpress.wp_term_relationships                    OK
wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy                         OK
wordpress.wp_termmeta                              OK
wordpress.wp_terms                                 OK
wordpress.wp_usermeta                              OK
wordpress.wp_users                                 OK

Repairing tables
wordpress.wp_options
warning  : Number of rows changed from 501 to 502
status   : OK
```

And then just restart your MySQL service.

Note:

> **Before you try to do the above commands, just make a backup of your database.**